# How can I access a function within a router javascript file via node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm handling with an webapplication that is not mine and now I've got to send a hundred e-mails.

Unfortunately, the code is not documented and not so well written, that means i have to go testing it to discover what I am able to do and what I'm not. but I don't know how to access this function that is on the code via node. Is it actually possible to do it? Here's the code:

```
  router.post('/aprovadosemail', miPermiso("3"), (req, res) => {
  var templatesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'templates');
  var emailTemplates = require('email-templates');

  // Prepare nodemailer transport object

  emailTemplates(templatesDir, function(err, template) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {

      var users = [];

      projetoSchema.find({"aprovado":true, "categoria":"Fundamental II (6º ao 9º anos)"}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(docs);
        docs.forEach(function(usr) {
          let url = "http://www.movaci.com.b/projetos/confirma/"+usr._id+"/2456";
          let url2 = "http://www.movaci.com.br/projetos/confirma/"+usr._id+"/9877";
          users.push({'email': usr.email, 'projeto': usr.nomeProjeto, 'url': url, 'url2': url2});
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          console.log(users[i]);
        }

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
          host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: "generic@mail.com",
            pass: "genericpassword"
          },
          getSocket: true
        }));

        var Render = function(locals) {
          this.locals = locals;
          this.send = function(err, html, text) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {

              transporter.sendMail({
                from: 'no-reply4@movaci.com.br',
                to: locals.email,
                subject: 'MOVACI - Projeto aprovado!',
                html: html,
                text: text

              }, function(err, responseStatus) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log(responseStatus.message);
                }
              });
            }
          };
          this.batch = function(batch) {
            batch(this.locals, templatesDir, this.send);
          };
        };

        // Load the template and send the emails
        template('rateada', true, function(err, batch) {
          for(var user in users) {
            var render = new Render(users[user]);
            render.batch(batch);
          };
        });
        res.send('ok');
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: being a developer You should move different code parts to separate functions. then inside of route handler just call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like previous dev did not knew `email-templates` package deeply (at least have not read how it works).

So in fact it has send method, You can create an email object from `email-templates` and pass necessary defaults, then You call `.send` method of it by passing dynamical parts - it just simply merge additional params passed in send arguments, sends mail using nodemailer inside of promise which it returns.

If it's interesting for You - read source code of it: https://github.com/niftylettuce/email-templates/blob/master/index.js

I tried to simplify it modular parts using promises.

I've not debugged it, but You may check my solution and fix it as You wish.

Have 2 files (to routing from handler separately, it may have variables that may conflict and etc):

1) `methods/users/aprovadosEmail.js`:

```
const
    Email = require('email-templates'),

const
    emailTemplatesDir = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../templates'),
    smtpTransportConfig = {
        host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: "no-reply4@movaci.com.br",
            pass: "some-password-here"
        }
    },
    createEmail = (template, subject) => {
        return new Email({
            views: {
                root: emailTemplatesDir,
            },
            transport: smtpTransportConfig,
            template,
            message: {
                from: 'no-reply4@movaci.com.br',
                subject
            }
        });
    },
    getApprovedUsers = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const criteria = {
                aprovado: true, 
                categoria:"Fundamental II (6º ao 9º anos)"
            };
            projetoSchema.find(
                criteria,
                (error, docs) => {
                    if(error) return reject(error);
                    const users = docs.map(doc => {
                        return {
                            email: doc.email,
                            projeto: doc.nomeProjeto,
                            url: "http://www.movaci.com.b/projetos/confirma/"+doc._id+"/2456",
                            url2: "http://www.movaci.com.br/projetos/confirma/"+doc._id+"/9877"
                        };
                    });
                    resolve(users);
                });
        });
    },
    sendMailToUser = (mail, user) => {
        return mail.send({
            message: {
                to: user.email
            },
            locals: user
        });
    },
    broadcastMailToUsers = (mail, users) => {
        return Promise
                .all(
                    users
                        .map(user => sendMailToUser(mail, user))
                );
    };

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const mail = createEmail('rateada', 'MOVACI - Projeto aprovado!'); // mail object
    getApprovedUsers()
        .then(users => broadcastMailToUsers(mail, users))
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Result of broadcast:', result);
            res.send('ok');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        });
};
```

2) current routes file where routing part that uses module file:

```
router.post(
    '/aprovadosemail',
    miPermiso("3"), 
    require(__dirname+'/../methods/users/aprovadosEmail')
);
```